# Joining Columns with different character set

Tags: mysql, innodb, join, mysql-5.7, character-set

I am joining two tables on varchar columns having CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin and one with CHARACTER SET latin1. Indexing is not working when i am joining these two tables on this column, I am only storing alphanumeric values english characters a-z, A-Z and digits 0-9, no lengthy strings (chinese characters/UTF16) or characters that takes more space .
I am working with Mysql InnoDB.

is this the normal behaviour?

Comment: *is this the normal behaviour?* Yes. Joining needs in string compare which needs in the same character set for definite collation to be applied. I.e. by fact the server uses joining by a function, like `ON t1.col1 = CONVERT(t2.col2 USING charset)`. So index cannot be used.

Comment: Since no index can be used, performance may suffer, especially for large tables.

Answer (score 0):

if you can be sure the join order,  for example, `a left join b`,
you can convert the column's character in `a` (in the query), make it the same to the column in `b`,then you can use the index in `b`.